# java scala cross compliation same module error java: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, gradle

I get this error when trying to reference a class under the `/scala` src directory from a class that exists in `/java` src directory.

(If the scala file is in the `/java` src file it doesn't compile either).

I am using Gradle to build the project.

## Scala class:

```
class Order {
    def foo(): Unit =
    { 
    }
}
```

## Java class:

```
 common.Order o = new common.Order();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]; I think you will not get much helpful feedback if you dont manage somehow to give us more specific information what you are trying.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the documentation of the Scala plugin, for Joint Compilation (Java uses Scala and / or Scala uses Java), put both, Scala and Java files that take part in the Joint Compilation in the `src/main/scala` directory.

Comment: That's what I said, isn't it? Or at least you need to move all Java files into the Scala folder that use Scala classes or are used by Scala classes.